# is there a way to draw on the screen using finger with Qml

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

is there a way to draw on the screen using my finger

i'm creating a **Blackberry-10** application like draw something as a school assignment

Answer (score 3):

If you have Qt Quick 2.0 available, you can make use the `Canvas` object in QML. The following sample shows how to draw a red line whenever there is a `onPressed` / `onPositionChanged` event:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    property int startX;
    property int startY;
    property int finishX;
    property int finishY;
    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint: {
          var ctx = getContext("2d");   
          ctx.fillStyle = "black";
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
          ctx.lineWidth = 1;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
          ctx.lineTo(finishX, finishY);
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.closePath();
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                startX = mouseX;
                startY = mouseY;
            }
            onPositionChanged: {
                finishX = mouseX;
                finishY = mouseY;
                parent.requestPaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you are planning to use what a BB10 because I didn't understood the question.

Try this solution from the [SDK documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/hello_nativesdk_main_1935868_11.html).

Comment: That appears to be the `Native SDK` not `QML` like the OP requested.